# Efficient way to find number of distinct elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, k-means

I'm trying to do K-Means Clustering using Kruskal's Minimum Spanning Tree Algorithm. My original design was to run the full-length Kruskal algorithm of the input and produce an MST, after which delete the last k-1 edges (or equivalently k-1 most expensive edges).

Of course this is the same as running Kruskal algorithm and stopping it just before it adds its last k-1 edges.

I want to use the second strategy i.e instead of running the full length Kruskal algorithm, stop it just after the number of clusters so far equals K. I'm using Union-Find data structure and using a list object in this Union-Find data structure.

Each vertex on this graph is represented by its current cluster on this list e.g `[1,2,3...]` means vertices 1,2,3 are in their distinct independent clusters. If two vertices are joined  their corresponding indices on the list data structure are updated to reflect this.

e.g merging vertices 2 and 3 leaves the list data object as `[1,2,2,4,5.....]`

My strategy is then every time two nodes are merged, count the number of DISTINCT elements in the list and if it equals the number of desired clusters, stop. My worry is that this may not be the most efficient option. Is there a way I could count the number of distinct objects in a list efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and probably most efficient is

```
len(set(l))
```

where `l` is the list. You can consider storing the data in sets instead of lists in the first place, if it is appropriate.

Note that for this to work the elements of `l` have to be hashable, which is guaranteed for numbers, but not for generic "objects".

Answer (score 1):

One way is to sort your list and then run over the elements by comparing each one to the previous one. If they are not equal sum 1 to your "distinct counter". This operation is O(n), and for sorting you can use the sorting algorithm you prefer, such as quick sort or merge sort, but I guess there is an available sorting algorithm in the lib you use.

Another option is to create a hash table and add all the elements. The number of insertions will be the distinct elements, since repeated elements will not be inserted. I think this is O(1) in the best case so maybe this is the better solution. Good luck!

Hope this helps,

Dídac Pérez

Comment: since I will be doing these checks every time I join two edges, inserting n elements into a hashtable for n loops (in worst case) will be n X n or n2 operation?